# what does this ping listing mean -- it does not have an IP address but some hex numbers

Tags: networking, ping, ipv6

Something's screwy on our network at work, and I'm no longer able to reach a server where I'm developing a database application. I'm not the network admin, and he's out sick.

When, from my workstation, I ping the server on which SQL Server instance lives:

```
  ping server6
```

this is the reply:

Pinging SERVER6 [fe80::6579:d35e:3471:f21c%11]

Why is there no IP address as there normally is? Is this an IPv6 address, and if so, why am I seeing it?

Comment: Yes. That is an IPV6 address and you are seeing it presumably because that's the address your machine found for that server when it queried DNS for the name.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is an IPv6 address. You're seeing this because ping will always display the IPv6 address for a host before the IPv4 one, if it has one. To see the IPv4 address, use:

`ping -4 server6`

(Assuming you are using Windows. It certainly looks like it.)

Comment: Not always. There are several rules that the OS uses to order IP addresses, defined in [RFC 6724](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6724). For example, Teredo-tunnelled IPv6 (2001:0::/32) has lower priority than IPv4 (::ffff:0:0/96).

Comment: @grawity Feel free to edit my answer as you probably know more about the subject than me :)